# How Can I Stop Power Query From Cutting of Data From The Left Side Of PDF Files It Imports

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to use PowerQuery to extract data from PDF files. When I load the data, Power Query cuts off up to 10-12 characters on the left side of the page.  For example:

Actual Data in PDF file column 1: **MALE 2YO 5NOV MS2**

What PowerQuery Imports:           **5NOV MS2**

Data Cut off from Column 1:       **MALE 2YO**

It's almost as if Power Query is importing the data under a page specification that is not consistent if the page specification of the PDF file. Is there a way to adjust this so that I can capture all the data on the PDF document?

Comment: Can you share the pdf?

Comment: @David is there a way I could email the pdf

Comment: Upload to a file sharing platform and paste a link in your question.

Comment: e.g. https://wetransfer.com/

Comment: you will need to add the https:// to the front

Comment: @David - were you able to access the sample file? I wasn't aware of wetransfer.  Nice resource, thanks.

Comment: @KJ it looks like you did not have the issue of the data being cut off.  Did you do anything special to achieve that output.

Comment: Thanks, but copy and paste defeats the purpose of an automated PowerQuery solution.  each file can include more than 100 pages. I'm hoping there is an alternative solution.

Comment: Your PDF looks corrupted so I'm not surprised PQ is failing. I'd work on your source file if I were you.